# `if a = 0 mod p then` in Maple only works when a = 0.

Tags: syntax, discrete-mathematics, maple

I need it to show the message every time a = 0 (mod p). But it only does it when a is actually 0. For example, if I plug Legendre(11,11), I get "-1".

```
Legendre := proc (a, p) 
local L; if a = `mod`(0, p) then 
"Coose a different integer";
else if a = -1 then 
L := (-1)^((1/2)*p-1/2); 
else 
L := `mod`(a^((1/2)*p-1/2), p); 
end if; 
if L = 1 then 
L else L := -1; 
L end if end if;
end proc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a = 'mod'(0, p)` should be `0 = 'mod'(a, p)`

See the [docs](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=mod).